# ARM Assembly error: A1898E: Target cannot be relocated. No suitable relocation exists for this instruction

Tags: arrays, memory, assembly, arm, embedded

I am trying to write simple program to sum up data in array, but I get this error

```
error: A1898E: Target cannot be relocated. No suitable relocation exists for this instruction
```

Here is my code

```
    AREA SUMARRAY, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT __main
    ENTRY
__main
    LDR r2, LENGTH
    SUB r2, r2, #1 ; r2 contains (LENGTH-1)
    MOV r6, #0 ; r6 sum set to 0
FOR_INIT MOV r1, #0 ; r1 index I set to 0
    ADR r3, ARRAY ; start r3 with address of A[0]
FOR_CMP CMP r1, r2 ; compare I and (LENGTH-1)
    BGT END_FOR ; drop out of loop if I < (LENGTH-1)
    LDR r4, [r3],#4 ; load r4 with A[I] then walk r3 down ARRAY
    ADD r6, r6, r4 ; update sum with A[I]
    ADD r1, r1, #1 ; increment I
    B FOR_CMP ; loop back to for-loop check
END_FOR
    STR r6, SUM ; store result in SUM
STOP B STOP
    AREA my_data, DATA, READWRITE 
    ALIGN
SUM DCD 0XFFFFFFFF
ARRAY DCD 1,5,20,32,13,66,3,5,23,64,112,66,22   
LENGTH DCD 13
```

Compiler says that problem is in this line

```
ADR r3, ARRAY ; start r3 with address of A[0]
```

What is wrong with this code ? Could someone explain why this error appears ? 
And how can I fix it ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
    AREA Sorting, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT __main
    ENTRY
__main
    LDR r2, LENGTH
    SUB r2, r2, #1 ; r2 contains (LENGTH-1)
    MOV r6, #0 ; r6 sum set to 0
FOR_INIT MOV r1, #0 ; r1 index I set to 0
    LDR r3, =ARRAY ; start r3 with address of A[0]
FOR_CMP CMP r1, r2 ; compare I and (LENGTH-1)
    BGT END_FOR ; drop out of loop if I < (LENGTH-1)
    LDR r4, [r3],#4 ; load r4 with A[I] then walk r3 down ARRAY
    ADD r6, r6, r4 ; update sum with A[I]
    ADD r1, r1, #1 ; increment I
    B FOR_CMP ; loop back to for-loop check
END_FOR
    STR r6, SUM ; store result in SUM
STOP B STOP
    LTORG
    AREA my_data, DATA, READWRITE 
    ALIGN
SUM DCD 0XFFFFFFFF
ARRAY DCD 1,5,20,32,13,66,3,5,23,64,112,66,22   
LENGTH DCD 13
```

But in this case I get errors

```
Error: L6286E: Relocation #REL:0 in sorting.o(SUMARRAY) with respect to LENGTH. Value(0x3fffff18) out of range(0 - 0xfff) for (R_ARM_LDR_PC_G0)
Error: L6286E: Relocation #REL:1 in sorting.o(SUMARRAY) with respect to SUM. Value(0x3ffffeb4) out of range(0 - 0xfff) for (R_ARM_LDR_PC_G0)
```

Comment: Now you need to load `LENGTH` and `SUM` to a register before using them.  Ie, replace `LDR r2, LENGTH` with `LDR R2,=LENGTH\nLDR r2, [r2]`.  You could also try `adrl` with the original (but I think fixing it just showed your two more linking issues).

Comment: what toolchain is this?

Comment: if the ldr rx,=address doesnt work then dont make the linker do it do it yourself.   in gnu it would be my_label: .word ARRAY then the adr replacement is ldr r3,my_label.   the my_label has to be in the same section  as the ldr instruction.  which is basically the problem you are having in general.  (it is not .data it is .text where you want this constant basically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation for `ADR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babcjaii.html):

> If *expression* is program-relative, it must evaluate to an address in the same code area as the `ADR` pseudo-instruction. Otherwise the address may be out of range after linking.

So one way of fixing the problem could be to move `ARRAY` to the same code `AREA` as the `ADR` instruction that references `ARRAY`.

Another possible solution would be to use the pseudo-version of `LDR` to load the address. That is, instead of `ADR r3,ARRAY`, use `LDR r3,=ARRAY` (note the `=` sign).
This way you should be able to keep `ARRAY` in the data `AREA`. Note that you may have to place [an `LTORG` directive](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Chedgddh.html) after the end of your `main` function.

Comment: For `LDR r2, LENGTH` to work, `LENGTH` would have to be within range for a PC-relative load. As it is located in a different `AREA` it is most likely _not_ within range. Load its address into another register first, then load the value, e.g.: `LDR r0,=LENGTH`, `LDR r2,[r0]`. And similarly for `STR r6,SUM`.